# Emulate IP address in Cloudflare for Geolocation

Tags: cloudflare, ip-geolocation

I'm using Cloudflare geolocation feature to enable the IP geolocation on our website.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/network/configuring-ip-geolocation/

However as part of testing we'd like to emulate the client IP address to ensure that our logic is working as expected.

Previously we had used MaxMind local DB and passed the IP through `X-Forwarded-For` header, however as now the DB is on Cloudflare it's not possible.

Is the an alternative similar way to emualte the IP with Cloudflare?